# Can pregnancy tests check for testicular cancer in men?

Tags: medical-science, cancer, pregnancy

I saw this picture [here](http://srsfunny.tumblr.com/post/77750220123/useful-information-http-srsfunny-tumblr-com):

[[image: reddit story]

Is this true? Can cancer be detected by a pregnancy test?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, most pregnancy tests detect human chorionic gonadotropin (hCG), a hormone produced by fertilized eggs, but also by some kinds of cancer cells.

You can read more about different tumor markers on this [info page](http://www.cancer.org/treatment/understandingyourdiagnosis/examsandtestdescriptions/tumormarkers/tumor-markers-t-m-blood-urine) from "The American Cancer Society".

There are also several other situations where a pregnancy test may give a false positive result (both for men and non-pregnant women). The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pregnancy_test) lists several possibilities:

> False positive test results may occur for several reasons, including
>   errors of test application, use of drugs containing the hCG molecule,
>   and non-pregnant production of the hCG molecule. Urine tests can be
>   falsely positive in those that are taking the medications:
>   chlorpromazine, phenothiazines and methadone among others.[10]
>
> Spurious evaporation lines may appear on many home pregnancy tests if
>   read after the suggested 3–5 minute window or reaction time,
>   independent of an actual pregnancy. False positives may also appear on
>   tests used past their expiration date.
>
> A woman who has been given an hCG injection as part of infertility
>   treatment will test positive on pregnancy tests that assay hCG,
>   regardless of her actual pregnancy status. However, some infertility
>   drugs (e.g., clomid) do not contain the hCG hormone.[11]
>
> Some diseases of the liver, cancers, and other medical conditions may
>   produce elevated hCG and thus cause a false positive pregnancy test.
>   These include choriocarcinoma and other germ cell tumors, IgA
>   deficiencies, heterophile antibodies, enterocystoplasties, gestational
>   trophoblastic diseases (GTD), and gestational trophoblastic neoplasms.

Comment: Snopes [rated it "partly true"](http://www.snopes.com/medical/disease/pregnancytest.asp).